# Solr - Date Query

Tags: solr

I am relatively new to Solr and I am trying to achieve the following: get all records where a certain field matches the current date (e.g. 16/04/2021 00:00 to 16/04/2021 23:59).

I have looked at the docs, but there aren't many examples.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on information in the [Working with dates](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/working-with-dates.html) section of the reference guide:

```
datefield:[2021-04-16T00:00:00Z TO 2021-04-17T00:00:00Z}
```

The `}` and the end indicates "not inclusive", so everything up to, but not actually inside the next day. You could use `.. TO 2021-04-16T23:59:59.999Z]` or something similar as well, but it's probably better to be explicit.